# fill delaunay triangles with colors of vertex points in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, delaunay, ggforce

here is a reprex

```
data<- structure(list(lanmark_id = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 
59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67), V1 = c(0.00291280916742007, 
0.00738863171211713, 0.0226678081211574, 0.0475105228945172, 
0.0932285720818941, 0.167467706279089, 0.257162845610094, 0.365202733889021, 
0.49347857580521, 0.623654594804239, 0.738846221030799, 0.838001377618909, 
0.911583795022151, 0.954620025430512, 0.976736039833402, 0.99275439380643, 
1.00100526672829, 0.0751484964183746, 0.136267471453466, 0.223219796351563, 
0.312829176190895, 0.396253287447153, 0.589077347394549, 0.682150866526948, 
0.771279538477539, 0.856242644022999, 0.915433541338973, 0.493665602840245, 
0.491283285973581, 0.488913167946858, 0.486968906096063, 0.384707082576335, 
0.43516446651127, 0.48730704698643, 0.541730425616146, 0.590794609520034, 
0.176234316360877, 0.230353437655898, 0.295908510434122, 0.350673723300921, 
0.2927721757992, 0.228392965512228, 0.634474821310078, 0.692554938010577, 
0.757884656518485, 0.809961553290539, 0.760324208523177, 0.696892501347341, 
0.299062528225204, 0.371899560139738, 0.440183530232855, 0.488448817156316, 
0.542120710507391, 0.613931454931259, 0.683122622479693, 0.614367295821043, 
0.544516611213321, 0.487065702940653, 0.43466839036949, 0.367662837035504, 
0.329392110306872, 0.439192556373207, 0.488617118648197, 0.543288506065858, 
0.652131615571443, 0.541622182786469, 0.486664920417254, 0.437126878794749
), V2 = c(0.201088019764115, 0.335422141956174, 0.468591127485112, 
0.597955245417373, 0.719502795031081, 0.826191980419368, 0.912263437847338, 
0.978932088608654, 0.996572250349122, 0.975164350943783, 0.906204543800476, 
0.817791059656974, 0.711167374856116, 0.587462637963028, 0.457981280500493, 
0.327526817895531, 0.19652402489511, 0.0832018969548692, 0.0247526745448235, 
0.00543973063471442, 0.0169853862992864, 0.0463565705952832, 
0.0442986445765913, 0.0151651597693172, 0.00747493463745755, 
0.0263496825405166, 0.0805712600069456, 0.160307477500307, 0.24640401358039, 
0.332244740019727, 0.420995916418539, 0.486383354389177, 0.505514985155285, 
0.521022030162301, 0.5059272511442, 0.48818970795347, 0.184054088286897, 
0.153658218058329, 0.153359749238857, 0.186997311695192, 0.20294291755153, 
0.204166125257439, 0.186997311695192, 0.153386090373069, 0.155932705636629, 
0.184603717976376, 0.203900583330345, 0.202836636618411, 0.670663080116174, 
0.635972857244521, 0.619932598923225, 0.632625553953685, 0.620132318139554, 
0.637530241507316, 0.668109937001625, 0.718821664744205, 0.73956412947459, 
0.744898219300658, 0.74046882628352, 0.720755964662638, 0.672731384920681, 
0.666152981987244, 0.670464844757437, 0.664772611108765, 0.671145517468628, 
0.673968618595099, 0.67986363963374, 0.675352028351748), coef2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.565178003460693, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.0433232019717308, 0.0433232019717308, 0.442833876807268, 
0.574211955093656, 0.574211955093656, 0.574211955093656, 0.574211955093656, 
0.442833876807268, 0.0433232019717308, 0.0433232019717308, 0.0612451242746323, 
0.0612451242746323, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.343056259557492, 0.701076795777046, 
0.674029769391816, 0, 0.538117834886036, 0.990039002564078, 0.451921167678043, 
0.701076795777046, 0.701076795777046, 0.316009233172263, 0.990039002564078, 
0.990039002564078, 0.878350036859346, 0.343364662128988, 0.282119537854356, 
0.282119537854356, 0.282119537854356, 0.343364662128988, 0.384793696241895, 
0.608382647917744, 0.608382647917744, 1, 0.608382647917744, 0.608382647917744, 
0.384793696241895, 0.501936678206125, 0.501936678206125, 0, 0.878350036859346, 
0, 0.501936678206125, 0.501936678206125)), row.names = c(NA, 
-68L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I used this data to create a deulanay plot in R

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

data%>%
  mutate(coef2 = coef2/max(coef2))%>%
  ggplot(aes(V1, V2))+
  geom_delaunay_tile(aes(colour = coef2, fill = coef2), alpha = .5)+
  geom_delaunay_segment2(aes(colour = coef2, fill = coef2))+
    geom_point(aes(colour = coef2))+
  ylim(1,0)+
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "magma")+
 scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma")+
theme_minimal()
```

which gives this
[image]

I want to fill all triangles with a blend of colors that match the color of each point, just as the lines are colored.

as you can see I have tried using  `fill = coef2` within de geom_delaunay but this doesn't really achieve what I want.

is there a way to do this in R.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With **ggplot2** I don't know. Here is what I did: I reproduced the Delaunay triangulation with **deldir**, and I represent it on a flat mesh with **rgl**. Because **rgl** is able to interpolate colors, and this is what you asked for, as I understood.

I used the `turbo` palette instead of `magma` because it is less dark.

```r
library(deldir)
del <- deldir(x = data[["V1"]], y = data[["V2"]])
# extracts all triangles
trgls <- triang.list(del) 
# look at the first two triangles:
head(trgls, 2L)

library(rgl)
library(viridisLite)
vertices <- cbind(data[["V1"]], data[["V2"]], 0)
faces <- vapply(trgls, function(trg) trg[["ptNum"]], FUN.VALUE = integer(3L))
colorfun <- colorRamp(turbo(200))
clrs <- colorfun(data[["coef2"]])
clrs <- rgb(clrs[, 1L], clrs[, 2L], clrs[, 3L], maxColorValue = 255)
mesh <- tmesh3d(
  vertices = t(vertices),
  indices  = faces,
  material = list(color = clrs)
)

# plot
open3d(windowRect = 50 + c(0, 0, 512, 512))
clear3d(type = "lights")
light3d(x = -50, y = 100, z = 100, ambient = "black")
view3d(0, 0, zoom = 0.8)
shade3d(mesh, meshColor = "vertices", specular = "black")
wire3d(mesh, color = "black", lwd = 2, depth_test = "always")
```

[image]